# Testing status for SagePay Form plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, opayo

I am providing maintenance for web site that is using "WooCommerce SagePay Form and SagePay Direct Gateway" plugin. To test some functionality I need temporary to turn on Testing status in "SagePay Form" section on Checkout tab of WooCommerce settings. Will I have any problems with returning to Live status? Do I need to contact support for activating account once again or everything is will be done automatically?

There is no clear answer on SagePay site. But there is a warning that after development stage is complete I need to turn on Live status and then it will be activated by the service. But what should I do after the account has already been activated?

Answer (score 0):

Sage Pay live and test sites are unconnected. Therefore you can go back to using the test site at will - live won't be affected, so there is no need to contact support when you want to use live. You can even use them simultaneously, if you wish.